# CSS Sprites- they all work but one

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

http://kilgourschameleons.com/new/test/index.asp

I have come across a very strange problem using css and sprites.  If you go to the link above you will see **all** the navigation rollovers work **but** "home".  I have used the same code for all the buttons and tried copying the ones that work and just replacing the name of the rollover, using things like "asdf" as the name in case "home" was reserved, etc.  This makes NO SENSE.

```
<div>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=960 height=104 border=0>
    </div>
    <center>
    <ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.asp" class="home active"></a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.asp" class="gallery"></a></li>
    <li><a href="care.asp" class="care"></a></li>
    <li><a href="products.asp" class="products"></a></li>
    <li><a href="sires.asp" class="sires"></a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.asp" class="faq"></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp" class="about"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
    <div>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=960 height=37 border=0>
    </div>
```

This is the css...

```
#navigation {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width:960px;
    height=55px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    margin:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
#navigation li {
    float: left;
}
#navigation li a {
    background: url("../images/navigation_bg.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
}
#navigation li a.home {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 148px;
}
#navigation li a.gallery {
    background-position: -148px 0px;
    width: 109px;
}
#navigation li a.care {
    background-position: -257px 0px;
    width: 84px;
}
#navigation li a.products {
    background-position: -341px 0px;
    width: 115px;
}
#navigation li a.sires {
    background-position: -456px 0px;
    width: 79px;
}
#navigation li a.faq {
    background-position: -535px 0px;
    width: 80px;
}
#navigation li a.about {
    background-position: -615px 0px;
    width: 120px;
}

}
#navigation li a.home:hover, #navigation li a.home.active {
    background-position: 0px -55px;
}
#navigation li a.gallery:hover, #navigation li a.gallery.active {
    background-position: -148px -55px;
}
#navigation li a.care:hover, #navigation li a.care.active {
    background-position: -257px -55px;
}
#navigation li a.products:hover, #navigation li a.products.active {
    background-position: -341px -55px;
}
#navigation li a.sires:hover, #navigation li a.sires.active {
    background-position: -456px -55px;
}
#navigation li a.faq:hover, #navigation li a.faq.active {
    background-position: -535px -55px;
}
#navigation li a.about:hover, #navigation li a.about.active {
    background-position: -615px -55px;
}
```

Comment: did you check out what it gives if another link was active?

Comment: Removing the active class from another element would block the hover effect BUT the hover effect for home wouldn't work SO you have an error in the background img position

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you get rid of the extra `}` in your css file?  Looks like it'll work.

Comment: I believe you got it.  Adding an extra `}` to the same place in this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHTRS/3/), then [breaks it](http://jsfiddle.net/KHTRS/4/).